# libGDX: Using PolygonRegion + Animation

Tags: animation, libgdx, textures, rendering, polygon

in libGDX:
I am currently using Animation for retrieving my renderable stuff.
Animation.getKeyFrame() returns TextureRegion. Up to now, I've been using boxes in my Games.
But, I would like to use PolygonRegion. As I understand, this would mean I would have to create a new PolygonRegion every time I getKeyFrame(). Is there a cheap way of getting PolygonRegion from Animation. Or is this cheap enough to not cause any rendering problems.

```
//per render()
textureRegion = animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
PolygonRegion polygonRegion = new PolygonRegion(textureRegion, regionVertices, new short[] {
            0, 1, 2,
            0, 2, 3
        });
```

Comment: You could have 1 `PolygonRegion`/`TextureRegion` and store them in a `Map`. The key could be the `TextureRegion`. It would also be possible to store them in an `Array` and select the right one, using the `stateTime` and `frameDuration`, just like `Animation` does. So you wouldn't recreate them every frame, but use them over and over.

Comment: @Springrbua the approach in my opinion is very good, but I do not know if, some utils to automate form creation poligon, on the other hand you can manually use to help support -> http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/

Comment: If you experience any initial error you can look at these questions might be errors with charger -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831011/physics-body-editor-error/29833387#29833387 and -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482503/bodyeditorloader-nosuchmethod

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments. I am working on it, I will post my reply as soon as I get the results.

Comment: @AngelAngel your links are all about Box2D, while the question does not seem to talk about Box2D or am i wrong?

Comment: @Springrbua You're right, I assumed he wanted to stop using boxes and use now forms for their collisions and associate a textureRegion, and the first thing that occurred to me was that it was box2d

Comment: @AngelAngel yea, the word `Box` with Libgdx often has something to do with Box2D, but in this case, i guess, it does not.